# Keras model has very good loss after 1 epoch but doesn't really get better with more epochs

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Hello I just wanted to ask this theoretical question.
What could be the causes of a model that has already a very good loss (0.004 on normalized data) after one single epoch but this loss doesn't really decrease over time (after 10 epochs it's still 0.0032).

Shouldn't it normally decrease way more over time?

The dataset is pretty big with bit more than a million datapoints and I didn't expect this very good loss just after 1 epoch.

So what could I change about this model or what am I doing wrong? (it's a densely connected NN predicting regression with adam and mse)

Comment: Sorry but this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities, but the problem needs some clarification.

Could you specify the range of your target?
0.004 might sound low as a loss, but it's not if your target ranges from 0 to 0.0001 for example.

What are the metrics of your validation & test data set? Loss on itself does not say much without knowing the validation loss.

Guessing that the 0.004 is too good to be true, your model might be over fitting. 
Try implementing dropout to avoid over fitting.

In case your model is not over fitting, it might be the case that Adam is overshooting a (local) minima. Try lowering its learning rate, or try sgd with custom hyper-parameters. This does take a lot of tuning.

There is a free course on Coursera called Machine Learning by Stanford. This covers theory on these concepts (and more) in a good way.